# Can we pass a Personalization String in Javascript Function in ExactTarget

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript

In ExactTarget, can we pass a Personalization String in Javascript Function?

So I Have function as below. e.g.

```
var DE = DataExtension.Init(DataExtension);
```

I have dynamic variable for the name of  "DataExtension" which I get from the URL Say:

```
var DynamicDataExtension = Variable.GetValue("@DataExtension");
```

Now I can use the

```
var DE = DataExtension.Init(DynamicDataExtension);
```

instead of

```
var DE = DataExtension.Init(DataExtension);
```

[ExactTarget: Data Extensions and Data Relationships](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/data_extensions_and_data_relationships/)

Comment: What is it that you're asking for here? What is the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Mark..I want use the dynamic value of data extension in the  DataExtension.Init(DataExtension); function. I am passing the value through URL so the data extension name will be different each time. I have tired this but this does not served my purpose.                                  `var DE =  Variable.GetValue("@data");`                                              `var DnamicDE = DataExtension.Init(DE);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Following your code, you would just set it to an AMPscript variable beforehand.

Like

```
%%[
SET @first_name = first_name /* here is your personalization string */
]%%

<script runat="server" language="javascript" >
    Platform.Load("Core","1");
    var firstname = Variable.GetValue("@first_name");
 //etc.
 </script>
```

etc.

Comment: You're welcome.  If it works, please mark this as answered.

Comment: Thanks @Timothy... So my question was I can use something like below..                                             `%%[
SET @first_name = first_name
]%%

<script runat="server" language="javascript" >
    Platform.Load("Core","1");
    var firstname = Variable.GetValue("@first_name"); var DnamicDE = DataExtension.Init(firstname );
 
 </script>`

Comment: Yes, I have done that very thing.